# Need to Insert then update a field in a table

Tags: php

Need help badly guys,

I have three tables tbl_questions, tbl_answers and tbl_link_qa

tbl_questions is where the questions from students get stored and tbl_answers is where the experts answer should be stored. tbl_link_qa connects the two tables in which the id number from tbl_questions gets stored in tbl_link_qa as q_std_id same idea with the id number from tbl_answers only that instead of insert, it updates if it finds an id number in tbl_link_qa without and expert id

i know this sounds confusing but I really need your help guys, I'm having my defense next week and I NEED to get this

here's my code:

i had to remove my update code since it was clearly not working T_T

```
$exp_reply = $_REQUEST['expertAnswerTypeBox'];  
$idnumber = $_REQUEST['exp_id'];
$std_question = $_REQUEST['question'];

$q_id = $_REQUEST['std_id'];


$sql2="SELECT * FROM tbl_teacher WHERE exp_id='$idnumber'";
$call_exp = "SELECT * FROM tbl_teacher WHERE exp_id='$idnumber'";

$call_std = "SELECT * FROM tbl_link_qa WHERE q_std_id='$q_id'";

$sql3="SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE question ='$std_quesion'";     
$results = "Insert into tbl_answers(answers,id_exp) values('$exp_reply','$idnumber')";
$insert_a_link = "Insert into tbl_link_qa(a_exp_id) values($idnumber)";
```

Comment: I see you building some SQL statements (be careful of SQL injection attacks here... you may want to sanitize your inputs more), but I don't see any code that actually does anything.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm doing a question and answer website which stores the questions coming from students into the database, forwards those questions to the expert if database is empty of answers then the expert replies, stores the answer to the database then sends the answer back to the student. I've got the parsing part done, whats left is to link all my tables together. tbl_questions + tbl_answers >> tbl_link_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index unique in your tbl_link_qa on field that you use to store question id.
Replace the last line to:

```
$insert_a_link = "REPLACE into tbl_link_qa(a_exp_id) values($idnumber)";
```

If the question already present in tbl_link_qa the row will be replaced by the new, if the question not present in tbl_link_qa the insert works normaly. This is what you want?

Comment: yeah, more like that. since the expert homepage has the "1 out of n" sign, indicating that there are n number of questions waiting to be answered. if there are 5 idnumbers present in the tbl_link_qa for the q_exp_id then the system has to answer those 5 idnumbers accordingly